# spark in arduino,relay and Bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

My problem is there was a spark when I plug in the voltage source of my 220 V bulb.I have my arduino uno r3,hc-05 Bluetooth Module,Relay Module and 220V bulb.
I cut the wire of my 220V Bulb.
One wire that is near to the bulb was connected to (COM)common connection of our relay.
The other cut was connected to ground.
The Relay Module's VCC was connected to Arduino's 5V.
The Relay's input pin was connected arduino's pin 13 as well as the Normally open(NO) pin of reay.The Relay's ground ws also connected to Arduino's ground.
My Bluetooth module tx was connected to aruino's rx ans Bluetooth module's rx was connected to tx.
I also connected Bluetooth Module,5v to the Arduino's 5v.
and A ground from Bluetooth module to Arduino's Ground.

I made my own version of schematic diagram and this is how it works.It is not that nice but I hoope you will understand.

The small squares serve's as the BreadBoard

https://twitter.com/n_galia/status/419876079403147264/photo/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple relay driver you can use with the Arduino. The component values are not super important, R4 could be larger, R3 can be larger, you can use just about any 5V relay and any NPN transistor. As show it should work with most low/medium sized relay. When active you can check the voltage between Q1's collector and ground. It should be less then a volt. About 4mA is provided by the Ardunio, far below it's output capacity.

PLEASE BE CAREFUL!!  you are working with high current and high voltage power. Blowing up an Ardunio is minor compared to the damage you can do to yourself.

[image: Arduio Relay Driver]

Comment: thak u so much sir..I am trying it right now..But I have this 5pins Relay,I am not that sure about the connection..

Comment: You can find the wiring with an Ohm meter if the wiring is not on the relay. Look for a pair of pins isolated from the others. confirm some resistance between those pins, more than 1Ohm and less than 1K.  That will be the coil. Check the other pins, two of them will be shorted together, reading 1 ohm or less. Those two are common (C) and normally closed (NC). The other pin is normally open (NO). You can guess at the Common pin and if your circuit actuates the relay and your lamp does not come on, re-wire to the other pin.

Please be careful.. and upvote my answer if you believe its good.

Comment: I tried connecting those normally open and normally close,and your right the circuit really actuates.and I tried rewiring it for the second time(it is stil based on your diagram);the common connection and the Normally close connection is already right..but then,my bulb doesnt respond to my arduino codes..

Answer (score 1):

The revised schematic might not work either. If your relay is a basic relay a driver will be required. The Ardunio can only sink about 20mA and it's likely your relay will need more to function correctly. The relay coil might look like a short to the Arduino.

If you have a relay with a built in logic level driver or a solid state relay, or even a TRIAC part (not a relay) you might be OK.

In situations like this its advised to use an optical coupler between the Arduino and the relay.

The optical coupler has a transistor that will dive the relay in its output, the transistor is actually a light sensitive transistor (photo-transistor) which is turned on via an LED built into the package. The Arduino would drive this LED (though a limiting resistor) which would activate the transistor to drive the Relay.  This way the low voltage electronics are totally protected and isolated from the high voltage stuff.

Comment: Your right sir..my relay was busted but my arduino was just okey.it works fine..i tried doing this one where i inserted transistor but i didnt insert my arduino yet, I am afraid .. I just woundering where to connect my arduino,can u helpme sir?

https://twitter.com/n_galia/status/420608489333866496/photo/1

Comment: thank you so much sir for the diagram..it hlps so much and My relay works now..the thing is my wires are sometimes cant connect..but it is manageable..thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!

The Arduino is not compatible of dealing with your 220Vac lines from power and to the light.

Your Arduino may not function correctly anymore.

I have attached a revision to your wiring.

[image]